# Google App Engine mysql schema migrations

Tags: python, mysql, django, git, google-app-engine

On a normal server, to update my codebase and any schema changes, I have a ticketing system, and my update script is something like:

```
$ git pull origin master && python manage.py run_sql_tickets
```

Google App Engine for Python has a nice hook which ties into the `git pull`, but how would I integrate pushing sql tickets to update the schema into the GAE project flow? Do I need to log into mysql each time and push these tickets in the shell?

Is there a way to run a `management command` when doing a GAE build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I found is...not really. The build environment for GAE is extremely restrictive, though you can use something like Codeship, CircleCI, or Jenkins.

After trying the above options, CircleCI (https://circleci.com/) is the one that worked for our needs.